# Kotlin (add configuration) no Run option

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I've been thinking about moving to Android development. I came from Java so I wanted to learn Kotlin with IntelliJ. I have never used a JetBrains software and I'm trying to follow a tutorial on YouTube.

The thing is none of the tutorials explain how to add a configuration to the project. For them a green arrow pops up when they create this function, but for me there is no run button and IntelliJ tells me I have to add some configuration?

```kotlin
fun main(){
    println("Hello World")
}
```

[image: Kotlin problem screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ doesn't seem to have recognised your `src` and `test` directories (since they aren't coloured blue and green, respectively).

When you create a new project, if you choose Gradle and then make sure to select Kotlin/JVM, it should set everything up for you correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but I solved this by putting the build system on gradle kotlin when I opened a new project.

[image: img]